# Odd behaviour using a custom dict class as the __dict__ attribute of Python classes

Tags: python, attributes, metaprogramming, magic-methods

I have a class that inherits from a dictionary in order to add some custom behavior - in this case it passes each key and value to a function for validation. In the example below, the 'validation' simply prints a message.

Assignment to the dictionary works as expected, printing messages whenever items are added to the dict. But when I try to use the custom dictionary type as the `__dict__` attribute of a class, attribute assignments, which in turn puts keys/values into my custom dictionary class, somehow manages to insert values into the dictionary while completely bypassing `__setitem__` (and the other methods I've defined that may add keys).

The custom dictionary:

```
from collections import MutableMapping
class ValidatedDict(dict):
    """A dictionary that passes each value it ends up storing through
    a given validator function.
    """
    def __init__(self, validator, *args, **kwargs):
        self.__validator = validator
        self.update(*args, **kwargs)
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.__validator(value)
        self.__validator(key)
        dict.__setitem__(self, key, value)
    def copy(self): pass # snipped
    def fromkeys(validator, seq, v = None): pass # snipped
    setdefault = MutableMapping.setdefault
    update = MutableMapping.update

def Validator(i): print "Validating:", i
```

Using it as the `__dict__` attribute of a class yields behavior I don't understand.

```
>>> d = ValidatedDict(Validator)
>>> d["key"] = "value"
Validating: value
Validating: key
>>> class Foo(object): pass
... 
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> foo.__dict__ = ValidatedDict(Validator)
>>> type(foo.__dict__)
<class '__main__.ValidatedDict'>
>>> foo.bar = 100 # Yields no message!
>>> foo.__dict__['odd'] = 99
Validating: 99
Validating: odd
>>> foo.__dict__
{'odd': 99, 'bar': 100}
```

Can someone explain why it doesn't behave the way I expect? Can it or can't it work the way I'm attempting?

Comment: I don't think you should ever replace `__dict__`, except in `__new__` - if you really must. What you are trying to do here should be done with a custom `__setattribute__` method.

Comment: To be honest, I am not really "trying to do something". I was writing the validating dict class, and just for fun wanted to try it as a `__dict__` instance. The reason for my question is that I really want to understand why it behaves like this, and whether it is possible to get around it (and how).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an optimization.  To support metamethods on `__dict__`, every single instance assignment would need to check the existance of the metamethod.  This is a fundamental operation--every attribute lookup and assignment--so the extra couple branches needed to check this would become overhead for the whole language, for something that's more or less redundant with `obj.__getattr__` and `obj.__setattr__`.

Comment: So, the answer is blatantly that metamethods on `__dict__` instances absolutely won't work? Can I assume from your knowledgeable answer (and your reputation) that you basically know exactly what you are talking about, and that I can accept this answer as all there is to be said about the issue?

Comment: It's hardcoded in Objects/object.c in `PyObject_GenericSetAttr`: if the object has a `__dict__`, it calls `PyDict_SetItem`, which sets the dictionary value directly without calling any metamethods.  I think that's also why you're not allowed to set `__dict__` to something that isn't a subclass of `dict`; if you try `x.__dict__ = []`, for example, it'll throw an exception.

Comment: I'd call it a bug that the Python docs don't mention this explicitly, though.  The *class* docs (not *class instance*) specifically say that `C.x is translated to C.__dict__["x"]`, and it's easy for people to see that and assume the same is true for class instances, so this could be clearer.  http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html